# How to call Vec<>::append() for a moved Vec<> argument?

Tags: rust, vector

I'm writing a simple builder. I'd like to have a builder method consume `self`, and also consume a `Vec<Node>` and append it to a `Vec<Node>` that `self` already owns.

I have this method:

```
pub fn with_nodes(mut self, mut nodes: Vec<Node>) -> Graph {
    self.nodes.append(&nodes);
    self
}
```

`nodes` is a non-reference because I want to consume it, and it's `mut` because `Vec<>::append()` mutates its argument.

Problem is, I get:

```
46 |             self.nodes.append(&nodes);
   |                               ^^^^^^ types differ in mutability
   |
   = note: expected mutable reference `&mut Vec<Node>`
                      found reference `&Vec<Node>`
```

How come that `nodes` is immutable, as it's explicitly marked `mut`? How else can I make the argument a locally mutable `Vec`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue isn't that `nodes` is not mutable, you need to explicitly pass a mutable reference to it as well:

```
pub fn with_nodes(mut self, mut nodes: Vec<Node>) -> Graph {
    self.nodes.append(&mut nodes);
    self
}
```

You can also avoid mutability:

```
pub fn with_nodes(mut self, nodes: Vec<Node>) -> Graph {
    self.nodes.extend(nodes.drain());
    self
}
```

Another tip, instead of repeating the type name in the return type, you can use `Self` instead of `Graph`. This makes refactoring easier.